# Extracting data to put in a variable from a list sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm trying to find a way to store in a variable of all the numbers from the players within allPlayers

I have been recommended to use the for loop which works but when you go to use it globally it only shows the last number not all of them. Preferably I would like it to be all within one line putting it into a variable but whatever is the simplest.

```
player1 = ['David.G', '1204', '4th Catogory']
player2 = ['John.D', '1000', 'Unranked']
player3 = ['Barry.M', '1932', '1st Catogory']
player4 = ['Steven.H', '1844', '1st Catogory']
allPlayers = [player1, player2, player3, player4]

for player in allPlayers:
    fideRankings = player[1]
    global fideRankings

print("")
print(fideRankings)
```

Result is:
1204
1000
1932
1844

1844

I was looking for it to print the same four numbers outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
player1 = ['David.G','1204','4th Catogory']
player2 = ['John.D','1000','Unranked']
player3 = ['Barry.M','1932','1st Catogory']
player4 = ['Steven.H','1844','1st Catogory']
allPlayers = [player1,player2,player3,player4]

for i in allPlayers:
    print(i[1],end=" ")
```

if you just want to print it outside of for loop:

```
player1 = ['David.G','1204','4th Catogory']
player2 = ['John.D','1000','Unranked']
player3 = ['Barry.M','1932','1st Catogory']
player4 = ['Steven.H','1844','1st Catogory']
allPlayers = [player1,player2,player3,player4]

string = ""
for i in allPlayers:
    string = string + " " + str(i[1])

print(string)
```

you can always use `string.split(" ")` to get those numbers in list if you need to use those numbers in future.

Comment: If you just want to print it outside of for loop see my updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> print([i[1] for i in allPlayers])
['1204', '1000', '1932', '1844']
```

This uses a list comprehension. It is equivalent to:

```
>>> ns = []
>>> for i in allPlayers:
... ns.append(i[1])

>>> ns
['1204', '1000', '1932', '1844']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty list to append the numbers then print it out all together. Like this:

```
player1 = ['David.G','1204','4th Catogory']
player2 = ['John.D','1000','Unranked']
player3 = ['Barry.M','1932','1st Catogory']
player4 = ['Steven.H','1844','1st Catogory']
allPlayers = [player1,player2,player3,player4]
empty_list = []
for player in allPlayers:
    fideRankings = player[1]
    empty_list.append(fideRankings)
print(empty_list)
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

```
player1 = ['David.G','1204','4th Catogory']
player2 = ['John.D','1000','Unranked']
player3 = ['Barry.M','1932','1st Catogory']
player4 = ['Steven.H','1844','1st Catogory']
allPlayers = [player1,player2,player3,player4]
print(" ".join([player[1] for player in allPlayers]))
```

result will be

`1204 1000 1932 1844`

or use as below if you need each player details in new lines

```
print("\n".join([player[1] for player in allPlayers]))
```

Result will be as below

`1204
1000
1932
1844`